# how tu update a column content on each tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql

i'm actually trying to update fields (meta_value) on a wp multisite,

my code actually work with one table

```
UPDATE 
wpsite_6_postmeta
SET meta_value = CONCAT(meta_value, ' [cf7ic]')
WHERE meta_value LIKE '% \"Your Name\"%' AND meta_key = '_form'
```

i'm trying to update that fields on each table (actually have more than 100 tables like wpsite_6_postmeta, wpsite_24_postmeta, ....

is there a way to update that column on each table of the database ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: is there a way to update that column on each table of the database - not without you writing code possibly using information_schema and dynamic sql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Get all the table names that end with `"_postmeta"`  Eg: `SHOW TABLES LIKE '%\_postmeta`. Then loop through each table name and update the `meta_value` field.